# Grant GAE-app access to a Google API with google-api-python-client

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-python-client

I'm developing a Google App Engine-app where one can fill out an online-form and based on how you fill it out a calendar post in a specific Google Calendar is created. What I'm wondering about is authorization in this type of situation where I want this form to be 100% publicly available and require no login whatsover to create the calendar post.

Using OAuth2 I have gotten the actual form and post-creation to work as I want but only when I'm signed in.

This is what I'm doing now, I have:

- One registered app, let's call it form-app(.appspot.com)
- One Google account, let's call it form-app-admin(@gmail.com) This account owns the Google Calendar that the posts are going in.
- One API Project owned by form-app-admin

I have used these and the google-api-python-client library (with its oauth2decorator) as in the Google App Engine-example so when I'm logged in as form-app-admin and surf onto form-app.appspot.com everything works exactly as I want it to but if I am not logged in as form-app-admin, naturally, it doesn't.

So what I would like to do is to kind of grant this permission to write to form-app-admin's primary calendar to the actual app rather than the user currently using the app. Or is there a better way?
The only premises is that anyone (logged into gmail or not) should be able to fill out the form and thus creating a post in some google calendar.

Naturally I would be very thankful if anyone happened to have the appropriate python code to achieve this but primarily I want help figuring out how to go about this since I have very little experience with auth-related stuff.

Thank you for your time!
/Tottish

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the [App Identity API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/overview). That page shows examples of how to use the API to assert identity to Google APIs.

Comment: Thanks! That looks to be the stuff, however I can't find any examples of anyone using it to access the Calendar API and when I try to use the example exchanging the data to fit my applicaction I get the error message: 
"The user must be signed up for Google Calendar."

I don't believe I can sign up a service account as a calendar user... Anyone know for sure that this should work with the Calendar API?

Comment: Here is the answer I got from a google-developer on the question if I can use the App Identity API:
"No, the App Identity API won’t help with Calendar because it requires user authorization."

Link:
http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/using-the-gae-app-identity-api-and-oauth2/

Comment: @Tottish Doh, sorry about that. In that case, your best bet is to create a role account that you use for this purpose, and embed the authentication credentials for it in your app.

Comment: OK, but is that really possible? As you can see from my post I already have the role account set up (the one I call form-app-admin@gmail.com) and I believe it is possible to access the API with the stored credentials as long as they're valid BUT can you really renew the OAuth2-token when it expires whithout the role-account being signed in? I read somewhere that Google is cycling some keys for the accounts (under the hood) to prevent this kind of behaviour. What do you think?

Comment: @Tottish I don't believe OAuth2 tokens should expire at all, unless explicitly cancelled by the user.